# Problems with psycopg2 cursor in Python3

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2

I am using psycopg2 with Python3 and I have just realized that if I make two queries in a row and the first one is wrong, the second one fails in spite of being right. Here is an example:

```
query_get_dbs_wrong = (
    'SELECT * '
    'FOM pg_database;'
)
query_get_dbs_right = (
    'SELECT * '
    'FROM pg_database;'
)

try:
    connecter.cursor.execute(query_get_dbs_wrong)
except:
    print('ERROR')

try:
    connecter.cursor.execute(query_get_dbs_right)
except:
    print('ERROR')
```

With this code I get two messages 'ERROR' in console, shouldn't I get only one? I need to manage the second one working in spite of the first one being wrong. I tried to close the cursor and reopen it, but the problem is still there.

Any idea, please? Thank you in advance.

**THE SOLUTION**

Add this line to any part of the exception code of each query:

```
connecter.rollback()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if I make two queries in a row and the first one is wrong, the second one fails in spite of being right [snip]. With this code I get two messages 'ERROR' in console, shouldn't I get only one?

Nothing to do with Python 3.

`psycopg2` defaults to autocommit off. So it opens a transaction when you run the first command. This transaction enters the aborted state when the first `ERROR` is thrown. As you don't do any explicit `ROLLBACK` on the transaction, the second command fails with an error indicating that the transaction is already aborted.

You are incorrectly assuming that catching the Python exception means that the database transaction can also ignore the error and resume. This is not the case. You must explicitly roll the transaction back (see the transaction control methods on the `connection` object) and begin a new one. Or you can use `SAVEPOINT`s, and `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT` on error - but be aware that this incurs a performance penalty in the database.

Comment: I think you have answered me some questions before this one. Thank you so much again! I am going to edit the question with the code in Python.